# Which direction indicates newer/older?

Tags: layout, pagination, labels

So I'm reading some blogs and I get to the bottom of the page when I see a graphic similar to this:

```
<< Newer Posts          Older Posts >>
```

This makes sense to me. But then, quite often, I'll see it reversed!

```
<< Older Posts          Newer Posts>>
```

This issue is compounded even further when the labels are changed:

```
<< Next                 Previous >>
```

It really, really makes me want to rip my hair out. What is the correct logic when specifying this type of information?

Comment: For webmail I've got used to the next page of older mail being to the right ->

Comment: If I remember correctly, Tumblr defaulted had an older-right model which I found irritatingly unnatural probably due to the book analogy.

Comment: "It really, really makes me want to rip my hair out." LOL!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The text should largely depend on the actual content itself. Is it time sensitive, like news, or is it content that will be relevant no matter when it is viewed? If it's time sensitive, it makes sense to use older/newer. If it's not time sensitive, previous/next seems like a better fit.

However, I would argue that adding page numbers would increase the understandability of your pagination because they would give you a starting index that's readily apparent and they would also provide more context for your pagination. Much of the confusion in the above methods results from either not knowing where you are, not knowing where you've been, or both. Page numbers help mitigate that problem, especially if you make it clear which page number the user is currently viewing.

As far as which should come first, older/newer, it depends entirely on your sort order. Again, however, adding page numbers here greatly minimizes the confusion.

What's more, for both usability and SEO purposes, you should provide more than just older/newer or next/previous.

Consider:

Suppose your blog is about business news. Which is most usable?

1. **Newer Business News** 1 2 [3] 4 5
   **Older Business News**
2. **Newer Business News** | **Older Business
   News**
3. **Newer** 1 2 [3] 4 5 **Older**
4. **Newer** | **Older**

Or let's say your blog isn't time sensitive. You instead publish business articles like best practices about marketing, hiring, strategy, etc. Which is most usable?

1. **Previous Business Resources** 1 2 [3]
   4 5 **More Business Resources**
2. **Previous Business Resources** | **More
   Business Resources**
3. **Previous** 1 2 [3] 4 5 **Next**
4. **Previous** | **Next**

Comment: Good insight - I like the idea of an alternative (as both a designer and a user)

Comment: It might be nice to just add this here since it seems relevant still: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ok-cancel-or-cancel-ok/ (and somewhat has to do with this). My two cents though is that we read from left to right in english, making me see that going to the right is newer (you keep landing on newer words), and that's why I add "new" to the right ->

Answer (score 13):

### Previous/Next or Older/Newer?

I find Older/Newer to be clearer.  On blogs that use Previous/Next without additional indicators, I'm always unsure whether Next means "show me the next thing that was posted" (the next newest set of posts) or "show me the next thing that I haven't read" (the next oldest set of posts).  I've seen both in use.

### Order

I prefer **« Older Posts** — **Newer Posts »**.  In my language/culture this is consistent with paper journals (the ancestors of blogs), graphs, and timelines.  I do actually read the link before I click it (which probably makes me an outlier), so the order isn't as important to me.

### What Others are Doing

**Seen on Popular Engines**

- WordPress: **« Newer Posts** — **Older Posts »**
- Blogger: **Newer Posts** — **Home** — **Older Posts**
- TypePad: **« Previous** | **Next »**

**Current Top 5 of the [Technorati Top 100](http://technorati.com/blogs/top100/)**

- [The Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/the-blog/): **« MM.DD.YYYY**
- [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com): **« Newer Entries** — **Older Entries »**
- [Gizmodo](http://www.gizmodo.com/): **« prev** 1 [2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 **next »**
- [Mashable!](http://mashable.com/): **« prev** 1 [2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 **next »**
- [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/): **« Older Posts** — **Newer Posts »**

It looks like some version of **« Newer Posts** — **Older Posts »** is the winner in this bunch, for whatever that's worth.  I'm not sure I'd actually want to copy some of these sites, but they are popular, so they probably represent what many users are accustomed to.

Amongst the sites listed that use Previous/Next, the convention is that "Next" is equivalent to "Older".

Comment: Two problems with this. First, your initial hypothesis is flat out wrong. Blogs are most definitely not about the time relationship between posts. I don't know where you are getting that from, and it makes absolutely no sense. Posts on blogs are almost NEVER intended to be directly related to each other.

Comment: (splitting to separate the separate thoughts) The second issue is that you appear to be talking about links on the posts themselves. Based on the text of the OP's example links, this is talking about paging on the LIST of posts, not an individual post. The list has a clear order displayed, so next and previous are definitely 100% clear in those situations.

Comment: @Charles -- If the time relationship is irrelevant, why does every blog in existence sort posts in reverse chronological order?

Comment: @Charles -- No, I am not talking about links on individual posts.

Comment: @ Charles -- I would think that the disagreement in the answers and comments here would be enough to at least suggest that Previous/Next is *not* 100% clear.

Comment: @Steve - Why do blogs sort in reverse chronological order? Because you have to sort somehow, and for ease of use, having newest at the top of your home page makes it easiest for people that regularly visit your site. However, you are talking about time mattering BETWEEN the posts themselves, and that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: You clearly are confusing yourself then, if you aren't talking about the links on the posts themselves. You wrote this: "When I click Next, do I want the next thing that was posted (the next newest post), or the next thing that I haven't read (the next oldest post)". Sure looks like you are talking about individual posts to me. Otherwise, why would you be talking about individual items here?

Comment: @Charles -- you've obviously never read blogs that detail a long construction process, or that refer to current events, etc.  Even sites like Engadget (for example) often have strings of related posts that discuss developing situations.

Comment: Having a list of results and next/previous links is definitely 100% clear. You people are just getting hung up on the fact that a blog sorts reverse chronologically and somehow think that next/previous need to mean the same thing as when dealing with time (e.g. Monday is the NEXT day after Sunday).

Comment: Think about other lists of data. Ebay is a great example. You can choose to sort in different ways, one of them being newly listed first. When you click "Next" there, you don't expect to see newer items, you expect to see older items. How is that not clear and how is that different than blog sorting?

Comment: Sure, I've read sites like that, and guess what? Those sites have links to the related posts right in them (in fact, you said that yourself). And if you read one of said articles, you aren't going to be going to the list of all posts to get to the related posts, you're just going to click on the links within that post. That said, even on sites like Engadget (since you mentioned it), having threads of related posts are NOT the norm.

Comment: One more thing, if blogs like you mention are so prevalent and routinely do have a ton of posts that relate to each other one after another, then they really shouldn't be using the blog paradigm, and SHOULDN'T be sorting every post in their site in reverse chronological order. They should be creating articles that have multiple pages if necessary, and then you can post the newest FULL articles first, with paging within them.

Comment: @Steve Kudos for the research! And FWIW, I've read plenty of blogs that do have a strong chronological component, so I find that your initial hypothesis is definitely **not** flat out wrong :).

Comment: Newer WordPress themes, e.g. on WordPress.com, appear to use "« Older Posts — Newer Posts »". However, many don't features a "Newer Posts" link at all instead providing only an "Older Posts" button that dynamically loads older content. That button is located either on the left or in the center of the page. With those themes if you go to `<blog>.wordpress.com/page/5/` you can't click your way to the content on page four directly.

Answer (score 10):

For L>R languages it should be Previous on the left, Next on the right. You're going 'forward' and 'backward' and this is the direction people read and turn pages.

To quote [Luke Wroblewski](http://www.uie.com/articles/previous_next_luke/):

> both Previous and Next could be thought of as primary actions and their placement should match the left to right motion associated with paginating a set of information.

Comment: Good point to make it similar to "reading a book"!

Comment: Couldn't have said this better my self.

Answer (score 3):

Time is usually represented from left to right on graphs so I'd suggest keeping with that. I.e. 'previous' on left and 'next' on right.

Next and Previous are unclear -- if at all poss labels should be qualified to indicate what they are relating to. Next Page, Next Most Recent or even better, how about Next (Jul 21).

Comment: Agree that Next Page and Previous Page are better than Next and Previous alone. But your time comment is an example why the links specifically should not use "Older" and "Newer" on blogs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using labels like "Older" and "Newer", then I don't think it really matters much. However, I think that using "Older" and "Newer" is incorrect, and "Next Page" and "Previous Page" are better labels. The reason for this is that most people associate links displayed like this as paging links, and as such, they expect it to work like this:

```
<< Previous                 Next >>
```

This is the opposite of your last example.

This follows the paging mechanisms used by searches (both site-level and search engines), so the user experience is well known.

I understand that the default for most blog platforms is to use the "older/newer" paradigm, but that actually leads to confusion. I can't count the number of times when I've clicked the "newer" link and been confused on a blog by seeing the list of posts I had just looked at. Why did I get confused? The "newer" link starts with 'N' and so does "next". I (like most users, I'm sure) are so used to seeing "next" and "previous" that that link starting with 'N' automatically gets associated with the next page of results, even if that's completely wrong.

Back to the order of "newer" and "older", I actually think that for blogs, the example that confuses you:

```
<< Newer Posts          Older Posts >>
```

makes more sense, because then at least the link on the right (pointing "forward") is the link to the next set of posts that you haven't already viewed.

**UPDATE:** Adding some additional information:

Take a look at the default for Wordpress (using their official blog as an example):

http://wordpress.org/news/page/3/

If you scroll all the way to the bottom, you will see Newer/Older displayed just as I lay out here. Now, take a look at the URL: *page/3/*

What URL would you expect to see when you clicked on "older posts"? *page/2/* or *page/4*? If there's any ambiguity here, then the links are poorly named.

What would you expect to see on *page/4/*? Would you expect to see older or newer posts? On a blog, you expect to see older posts. Since the number is increasing, then the "Older" link definitely makes the most sense to be on the right, since that's how the paging design pattern works (Don't believe me, look at this site, google, anything you want).

Because people clearly understand that the display of a blog does not follow an oldest to newest pattern (although comments and answers on this page seem to contradict that), and people DEFINITELY understand the paging pattern ("forward" takes you to the next page) it makes more sense to not even display older/newer. Hence the reason that next/previous are a better option. If a user is on the above URL, and they click Next, they definitely would expect to see *page/4/* (already resolves the ambiguity issue). And because in general, users DO know that the front page of a blog has the newest posts, they know what they are going to be getting when they click Next from that page.

Comment: I think maybe a more informative label entirely would be beneficial to the end user - perhaps the date range of the last group of postings, or something similar. I think of `<<` as back and `>>` as forward, but the time relationship is unique in the blog setting.

Comment: @melee - The time relationship isn't really all that important on blogs. As a user, I don't really care what date a post was written (in general), especially when I am sitting there and browsing through the list of posts. If I care about the date of a specific post, I can look at the post (either on the list screen or the detail screen).

Comment: @Charles -- Isn't the time relationship kind of the point of a blog?  If it wasn't, why wouldn't you just post a bunch of essays and sort them alphabetically by title?  I may not care about the specific date (unless I want to know how recent the information is...) but I definitely care which posts came first and which ones came later.  Previous/Next provides absolutely no useful information, especially since the meanings are reversed on some blogs.  Older/Newer at least tells me what direction I'm going.

Comment: I find your association between "going forward" and "Older posts" (last couple of paragraphs) very confusing. It only makes sense to me if you are always reading posts in reverse chronological order (in which case older posts are the ones you haven't read yet). I hate reading them in that order, because you lose the train of thought of the writer and I therefore always start with the oldest post I haven't yet read. Going forward to me is then very logically associated with "Next" and "Newer" and the right hand side of the page (for the link).

Comment: @Steve - Previous and Next page are perfectly clear when you are reading a blog. Posts are listed from newest to oldest, so the next page would bring you to the next page of results. It's just like search - next takes you to the next most relevant results. On blogs, next takes you to the next most recent posts. Just because some sites are completely wrong (your case of some blogs reversing the meaning) doesn't mean that next/previous isn't the way you should go.

Comment: @Marjan - You are most definitely NOT the normal user based on what you are saying here. I've done user testing on this sort of thing, and I actually saw people doing the same thing that I have done when seeing "Newer" - They see links that look like paging links and treat them accordingly. Also, I don't agree with your statement of losing train of thought of the writer if you read newest items first. Blogs are not intended to be one long stream of consciousness. On 99.99999999999% of blogs, I'm quite sure that posts are intended to be stand-alone.

Comment: @Marjan - One more thing, the next page having older results has nothing to do with the order that you are reading them. It has everything to do with the order that posts are displayed on the site. Just look at just about any site that runs on wordpress - Even when it uses Newer/Older, it still has the Older link pointing forward (>>) because that is the NEXT page of results.

Comment: @Charles Boyung I got so confused/frustrated by this scenario that I actually wrote the question wrong. I agree that << Newer/Older >> is the most logical to me.

Comment: @Charles: Great, I like not being "normal" (read average). And, well, to me previous and next page actually **do** have something with the order in which I read the posts... I often skip reading a blog for quite a while and then come back to it. Also losing the train of thought is something that can happen easily with technical blogs where one post often builds on the information provided in an older one. I guess I mostly read technical blogs...

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of Hisham's answer, another way would be to have a vertical scheme:

**^ Newer - Older v**

That would maintain some kind of mapping between posting date and the typical "temporal direction" of blogrolls.

Answer (score 1):

(My bad: I completely missed that it's a blog. See comments)

To me, the first one makes the most sense because it's how you read a book.  "Next" or "Newer Posts" would go on the right because, unless it's Hebrew or Arabic, you always turn the page on the right to go to the next page.

Not quite related, but in a talk at the Business of Software conference, Don Norman gives the example of a remote that has up/down arrows.  Which button would make the most sense to go to the next or previous channel?  The **[video](https://vimeo.com/96714148)** is worth watching for UI and usability folks.

Comment: The problem with your logic is that blogs are not read like books. You don't read oldest to newest. Blogs have the newest posts first, and when you go to the next page, you are reading older posts, not newer. This is why using "newer" and "older" instead of "next" and "previous" is a less desirable model, because like Julian said in his answer, time is usually represented from left to right.

Comment: So books in right-to-left languages are printed so that the binding is on the right? I was wondering about that.

Comment: +1 Everyone participating in this question should **watch that video**. It's enlightening.

Comment: Good point, Charles. I was thinking more of an eBook or PDF.

Comment: Without having seen the entire video, the fundamental problem here is, that a hyperlinked medium, such as a website with "flat" pages isn't good at representing neither temporal nor spatial relationships between elements on different pages.

Answer (score 1):

Blog articles being chronologically ordered, it does not seem backward to use 'Older | Newer' instead of 'Previous | Next'. In fact, it's even more appropriate from a semantics angle. So here, it's 'Semantics VS Convention'. Personally, I would dare use 'Older | Newer' as I think it has gained enough acceptance not to miss sleep over possible user confusion.

Regarding the other question: whether to use 'newer | older' or 'older | newer'... Assuming the language is LTR, I'd say it depends how the post age correlates with the reader's interest. The following example may help illustrate my last statement:

> Would one open up a blog to relate an event while experiencing this very event, anti-chronological order seems more appropriate - that is, having the home page display the latest article, and the pager being 'Older | Next'. Should this blog be stopped ('archived') at the end of the event, perhaps reversing the order could be an interesting choice.

Answer (score 1):

To add a physical action / technical note as to why a programmer would not asses the UX but give what the system gives.

Normally the default way data list is returned from the database is with the most relevant or newest record first. To use MySql syntax this would be record number 1 (or [0] in array). So the query will be first 20 results or LIMIT 1,20. To get the "next group of 20" you are effectively going down 20 or two the right.

You are going back in time or less relevant. A western mind and without thinking too much, a user wants the latest story and then goes back in time to look for previous references. This is how we quote past texts in writing as well. It would be hard to think about I have spent time reading but within this source there might be future articles that are better so I will look into the future (well why wasn't I reading that one).

So the next set of the results is page 2 showing 21-40 or LIMIT 2,20 and so you are "paging" right.

Second point is the physical, reinforcement of that. The best place for a link to action is bottom right as we read top left to bottom right so this going back in history to PREVIOUS> or OLDER> is in a good place to hit on the right. If its is on the left which makes sense for the words you are in effect covering the page with your hand to click bottom left and that does not feel comfortable.

The only time I tend to flip this is for label tags on sliders/carousels/rotating lists of things that in effect you always are in the middle of as they go in a circle, so NEXT> makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If they are listed down chronologically  wouldn't you do something like this?

Title of Post 1
11/10/2011

Title of Post 2
11/08/2011

More Posts >>

I feel even though they are dated older, I'm still moving to the 2nd page of items, or moving through them like I would next through a list of pages, or through older email or something.