# Link to older posts should point to the left or right?

Tags: website-design, terminology, pagination, link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which direction indicates newer/older?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/which-direction-indicates-newer-older)

At the end of a list of blog posts there is often a link to previous posts. Somtimes this link is extended with an arrow pointing to the right or to the left. What would you say, is more common?

```
older posts -->
```

Or

```
<-- older posts
```